# Why won't these bonders bond?

Tags: spacechem

You can see where this is going...

[image]

The red and blue waldos are about to cross over bonder tiles with a **BOND +** command on the bonder near the bottom left of the screen.

The problem is nothing seems to bond!  Thinking it may be a bug, I've tried restarting the game and rejiggering the red path to drop the carbon atom onto the bonder, perform **BOND +**, then grab it again to no avail.  I've also tried sending the blue waldo over a **BOND +** command without success.  Searches online have found a couple other people in similar situations with no apparent resolution.

I love this game, but this is aggravating!  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Huh.  That looks like it SHOULD bond.

Comment: Perhaps the game is mistakenly enforcing a bond limit? Not sure. Looks like it should work.

Comment: Have you tried swapping the bonders? [The bonders themselves are numbered internally to fire in a particular order](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/39153/3936), though in theory that shouldn't affect this setup you could still try it to see what happens

Comment: @YiJiang, yes, I tried shuffling the bonders.  No luck.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is a [Disassembly Reactor](http://spacechem.wikia.com/wiki/Disassembly_Reactor); you can tell because the bonders have a small '-' symbol instead of the typical '±' symbol. The bonders in this reactor can only break bonds, not create them.

Comment: I guess I will accept the game author's solution. :)  Thank you so much!  (And thanks for an amazingly addictive and smart game.)