# Sequential outing problem

Tags: spacechem

Playing spacechem now for a few days.

I was looking up some of the solutions on solution-net and attempted the fastest dissassembly for methane in nothing works level. From least cycles leaderboard, fastest solution reactor 2 (http://spacechem.net/solution/nothing-works/34239)

Anyway, on his solution the out symbol seems to out two free hydrogens in the output simultaneously, whereas when I try his solution, my out symbol wants to output atoms one/cycle causing collisions...

was this something that changed between versions? If so, then the stats are a bit flawed if the solutions are not replicable on current versions of spacechem.....

jer

Comment: If my memories serves me right in every version of the game I've played (though it's been a few months since I played) the OUT command will always output one molecule per cycle.

Answer (score 4):

I've just tested the linked solution in my copy of spacechem and both found your problem and its solution.

The solution works in the current (steam) version but requires that the individual bonders be placed in the correct order, see [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/39153/27204) question for more details about this hidden feature. Unfortunately there is no way to determine the correct order of the bonders other than switching them around until the solution works.